# Pokemon Type Encounter Abilities

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I just heard Prof. Sycamore say that Static increases Electric type Encounters.
The only other ability like this was Magnet Pull for steel. I was unaware of Static though. Are there more type specific encounter abilities? and what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static and Magnet Pull are the only abilities that affect the chances of the type of wild Pokemon that can be encountered in the grass.

Other abilities such as Intimidate, Illuminate, and White Smoke also affect the encounter rate, but in a different way.

Comment: And Sweet Scent increases the chance of a Horde encounter IIRC. Which is a move not an ability, so it's only tangentally related to this question

Comment: Sweet Scent immediately starts a Horde encounter unless the area you are in doesn't have any.

Comment: I also believe Sweet Scent does not work if it is currently raining on the route you are on. But this was just an observation a friend made to me and not something I have noticed myself.

Comment: Did Static have this effect even before 6th Gen? This is the first time I am hearing about this!